# Android/Eclipse dev: Error trying to run: aapt Unknown option '--debug-mode'?

Tags: android, aapt

Helo guys, I have the following problem trying to run my very first HeloWord app for Android, using Eclipse, the console says:

[2011-01-07 01:45:45 - HelloWorld] ERROR: Unknown option '--debug-mode'
[2011-01-07 01:45:45 - HelloWorld] Android Asset Packaging Tool

I have in the SDK Manager, in Installed Packages:

Android SDK Tooks, revision 8
Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 6
SDK Platform Android 2.2, API 8, revision2
Tools R06 Windows Package, revision 6

I can see the emulator just fine...but I can't just make this first tutorial run, even I haven't touched the Eclipse generated code! HELP!!! :)

Comment: Try Clean the code and run again